# how to calculate switch delay for entire file?

Tags: security, host, data-communication

I have a link between 3 hosts and 2 switches,  20GB file to send over, switch one has 10  μs and switch two has 20  μs? Is it right that to calculate the SWITCH DELAY FOR ENTIRE FILE= NUMBER of packets x ( switch one delay + switch two delay) ? and what if both switches has the same delay time?